# Getting mean and standard deviation from a histogram

Tags: matlab, octave, histogram, mean

is it possible for me to get the mean and standard deviation for that specific bar(bin) in a histogram? If yes, what are the function or command that I should use?

For example,
Let say I have a matrix of (1000,1) measurements and I would like to group it in a histogram.
The y-axis is the number of measurements and x-axis is the measurement. For x-axis, we will have a range of 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39 and so on. How do I possibly get the standard deviation and mean of just the 20-29 range?

I am using octave.Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it.I am using Octave by the way

Comment: Lets see your code for calculating the histogram first?

Comment: I am using the hist(x) function.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you can get that information form the histogram itself, I think you'll need to get it from your original data.

```
data = rand(1000,1)*100;
```

Extract the data that falls in your bin

```
data_subset = data(data >= 20 & data < 30);
```

Then just get the mean and std

```
m = mean(data_subset);
s = std(data_subset);
```

I guess you want to get all the bins done in one shot and for that you'll need `accumarray`:

```
data = sort(data);
bin_size = 10;
subs = ceil(data/bin_size);
M = accumarray(subs, data', [length(unique(subs)),1], @mean)
S = accumarray(subs, data', [length(unique(subs)),1], @std)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was thinkning if it is possible to directly getting the mean and standard deviation from the histogram bin itself.Apparently not =(

Comment: @user3082696 I'm sure you can't. That info is not in a histogram. But I've added code for how to get it in one easy shot using `accumarray`